# Kerberos SSH/PAM login like AD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, kerberos, pam

I've recently been trying to set up a new Ubuntu server environment, we've wanted to set up a single sign on system that functions similar to good old Windows AD. In this case you would SSH with a kerberos username and password and you are authenticated as usual, and created a local home directory if you dont already have one and can proceed as a normal local user.

In this case all of our servers are Ubuntu Server 16.04/16.10, and this cannot be changed.

I've followed along and studied with the O'Reilly book 'Kerberos: The Definitive Guide" and from here I've managed to set up my KDC and DNS, as far as I can tell, correctly. The problem appears to be when I try to set up a client. I poke the krb5.conf file to the right places, make sure I have user principals but whenever I try to log in, it hangs for a second then authentication fails with the error: `Decrypt integrity check failed` in auth.log

In this case I'm using the PAM module `pam_krb5.so` and `pam_mkhomedir.so` to create a new user home directory. These were set using Ubuntu's `pam-auth-update` utility.

I can get kerberos tickets just fine if I manually `kinit` from the client machine, but login seems to completely fail.

For a while we tried to evaluate FreeIPA but that seemed to fail spectacularly and un-resovably on Ubuntu for us, it seemed like more trouble than it's worth.

I'm really not sure what I'm missing here, and every time I try to find information on the subject it feels like I'm missing some crucial step that's expected of me but no one seems to tell me?

Thanks!